# What theorem is this in the infinite dimensional case?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

The spectral theorem for compact, self-adjoint operators is as I have understood the infinite dimensional case for orthogonal diagonalisation of a symmetric case in linear algebra?

But in linear algebra we also had that if a matrix had enough linearly independent eigenvectors we could diagonalize it(not orthogonally). Does this "theorem" have a counterpart in the infinite dimensional case?